# Am I allowed to include Chrome Webdriver in an open source project?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, github, dependencies

I have a open source project on Github, I'd like it to include everything needed to run the project.

I use Selenium + Chrome driver in the project. Am I legally allowed to include/distribute the `driver.exe` file? Is there a better way to handle this (E.g somehow using dependency management to include the executable)?

Example of how the executable is used (Java):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "location")
```

Comment: Half of this sounds like a question for a lawyer, which we likely aren't. You could look at the Chromedriver documentation and see if they talk about fair use, etc. You might send this question to the Chromedriver team.

Comment: Check out https://www.chromium.org/Home.  AFAIK, they maintain `chromedriver`, and google builds the `chrome` browser out of their open-source project.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_(web_browser) discusses some licensing of the browser, but I'm not qualified to give legal advice.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webdriver manager. This library will automatically download a chrome or any other browser driver on runtime, so you can get rid of the executable files from the project. Below is the maven dependency for the library.

[Maven dependency for webdriver manager](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/3.7.1)

Comment: This is the solution I went with, worked perfectly for me thanks!